# Why different initial parameters of Expectation–Maximization (EM) result in different clusters?

Tags: clustering, expectation-maximization

I'm having a hard time understanding conceptually why we get different clusters when we start the algorithm with different initial parameters. Can anyone explain the mechanisms behind it to me a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

EM is an iterative algorithm. We let some initial parameters $\theta^{(0)}$, from which we deduce $\theta^{(1)}$, then $\theta^{(2)}$ etc.

At step $t$, we can write:
 $\theta^{(t)} = G(\theta^{(0)})$ for a certain function $G$. There is no reason for $G$ to be identity.

---

We let $L(\theta; \mathbf{x})$ the likelihood of dataset $\mathbf{x}$ given $\theta$. If we remember how EM works, it only ensures that likelihood is nondecreasing:

$$L(\theta^{(0)}; \mathbf{x}) \leq L(\theta^{(1)}; \mathbf{x}) \leq L(\theta^{(2)}; \mathbf{x}) \leq \ldots$$

but say nothing about how good is $\theta^{(t)}$ (for example compared to the maximum likelihood estimator).

---

The same behavior (different initial parameters leading to different clustering) is happening for K-means algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with different starting conditions, you can find different local optima.

See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point

Finding the global minimum is way too expensive. If you try a few times, and the data is well behaved, you will likely find the global one by chance at least once.